# How to identify port of switch which is connected to client PC from the Server PC? Server PC is having windows OS

Tags: networking

How to identify port of switch which is connected to client PC from the Server PC? (these two PC's are connected using socket.) In between these two pc's communication path there can be multiple switches. Please help me is there any way to achieve this.